# Passing current line as argument to external command

Tags: normal-mode, external-command

Say I have a file with contents:

```
abc
def
https://www.google.com
```

and my cursor is on the 3rd line.

How do I:

1. run wget/curl with the contents of that line as argument (in particular, not pass the line as stdin)
2. same as above but put the output onto the line below

I understand `%` represents the current file and `.` represents the current line. How do I use `.` to send it to wget (or other command)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$ man xargs` to convert `stdin` into an argument:

```
:.!xargs curl
```

But, used that way, the line will be replaced with curl's output.

If you want to see the output without messing with your buffer, you can use `:help :w_c`:

```
:.w !xargs curl
```

If you want to insert curl's output below the current line, you can use `:help :put` and `:help system()`:

```
:put=system('curl ' .. getline('.'))
```

Comment: Oh, how did I miss using xargs to convert stdin into an argument. Thanks.

Comment: To get the output in the line below, rather than use `put=system...` I found my workflow was smoother by copy pasting the line (yy followed by p) and going to the line below and running  `.!xargs curl` per your first recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Another potential option is `:read !curl` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>. The latter keys insert the WORD under the cursor, but you could equally use `"ayy` to yank the line into the `a` register and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> to paste it.

Contrary to romainl's comment earlier, this use of `:read` should *not* break the alternate file, since no file name is given.

Comment: Another possible improvement if do insert line to cmdline a lot. `cno <expr> <C-r> YourWrapperCtrlR()`, then `C-r> l` in cmdline to inset `getline('.') to cmdline.

Comment: @qeatzy see `:help c_CTRL-R`; `C-r C-L` is already valid for the current line